# Update appointments in one service call using EWS managed API 2.0

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010, ews-managed-api

I'm setting a custom extended property for each existing appointment like that:

```
var extendedPropertyDefinition = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(DefaultExtendedPropertySet.PublicStrings, "RateTheMeetingId24", MapiPropertyType.Integer);
var propertySet = new PropertySet(PropertySet.FirstClassProperties) { extendedPropertyDefinition };
appointment.Load(propertySet);
appointment.SetExtendedProperty(extendedPropertyDefinition, meetingId);
```

and than I'm updating appointment:

```
appointment.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite);
```

it works fine, but very slow, because Update() creates a call to exchange for every appointment. I would like to update meetings in one single call. I can make list of my appointments with setted custom property and than i would like to use something like that:

```
UpdateAppointment(List<Appointment> appointmentsWithExtendedPropertySetted)
{
    appointmentsWithExtendedPropertySetted.UpdateAll();
}
```

i have found a reference in MSDN about UpdateItems method:
[ExchangeService.UpdateItems method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeservice.updateitems.aspx)

but i don't know how to use it.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: thanks, i will keep it in mind :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got asnwer how to solve my probem i msdn forum:
[update appointments in one service call](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/ec401472-3aa5-4d16-a103-58d9242cdc4a/c-update-appointments-in-one-sevice-call-using-ews-managed-api-20#d2864f26-20b6-433c-b382-d8312830917c)

I need to set property for one appoitment at the time and then add it to batch, after i set properties for all appointments i need to use _service.UpdateItems() method for my appointments batch:

```
pulic void UpdateAppointments(List<Item> _updateBatch)
{
    Service.UpdateItems(upUpdateBatch, Folder.Id, ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite, MessageDisposition.SaveOnly, SendInvitationsOrCancellationsMode.SendToNone);
}
```